# REST - Download list of users

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

**Context:**

I want to write an endpoint that will return a `Collection` of users based on their usernames. How should those username be passed to the REST endpoint - *note that I can (potentially) have a lot of usernames (say > 5000)*?

**Solution #1:**

Use a `GET` endpoint, concatenate the usernames on client side and pass them as a single request parameter. Split the request parameter on server side to get the list of usernames.

```
@RestController
public class UserController { 

    @GetMapping
    // able to deserialize `filename1,filename2` to List out of the box
    public Collection<User> getUser(@RequestParam List<String> usernames) {
        return userService.getUsersByUsername(usernames);
    }

}
```

**Solution #2:**

Use a `POST` endpoint and pass the list of usernames as request body. Although cleaner form a coding perspective, I end up using a `POST` to fetch data.

```
@RestController
public class UserController { 

    @PostMapping
    public Collection<User> getUser(@RequestBody List<String> usernames) {
        return userService.getUsersByUsername(usernames);
    }

}
```

**Questions:**

1. Which of the two solutions would be the better approach?
2. Do you have a better approach to pass the list of usernames into the endpoint?

**Edits:**

- I've updated the signature of the first solution based on suggestions from answers. Spring is able to deserialize `filename1,filename2` to List out of the box for `@RequestParam`.

Comment: Given the amount of data as parameters, you'd better go with the `POST` solution. It will also be easier to test things with tools like postman.

Answer (score 1):

`POST` looks like a cleaner approach in this case because -

1. Sending a huge string in a URL is not a good idea and there is scope for error
2. You need to write additional code (logic) to create the string on frontend and split it on backend.
3. Sending a huge string in a URL is not scalable as there are limits on the length of URL.

Answer (score 0):

Get approach might result into an issue since URL length is limited and then you have to limit your query parameters.

Though its not a post request but in your case i think post is the only way out.

Answer (score 0):

GET is not limited, yet the browser is. Your server client does not seem to be the browser, so I would say GET is the way to go.

**P.S** GET can receive a body (not so great, but POST is not also the best match).

You don need to concatenated the string and add extra computation on server server, GET can receive a list of separate strings.

UPDATE with example:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/test")
    public List<String> getTestParams(@RequestParam List<String> params) {
        return params;
    }
}
```

The test with 3000 params

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class TestMyController {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testRequestWithParamsList() {    
        List<String> params = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
            params.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        List<String> result = restTemplate.getForObject(buildUrl(params),
                List.class);

        assertEquals(params, result);
    }

    private String buildUrl(List<?> params) {
        return "/test?params=" + getUrlParameter(params);

    }

    private String getUrlParameter(List<?> params) {
        return params.stream()
                .map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    }
}
```

If you are using tomcat you must specify also the max http header property in application.properties

```
server.max-http-header-size=30000
```

Comment: The GET request body can be tricky, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: Do you have a working snipped of receiving a List<String> as `@RequestParam`? See https://pastebin.com/9aBZXqQ1 for some snippets.

Comment: Updated with example

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with all the answers given above. I would like to specify one more point , if you are going with post request you might have to increase the payload capacity a server can receive , the default post capacity(The maximum size in bytes) of spring boot is 2mb (based on your server). While testing your code might work fine with 1000-2000 usernames but make sure to change the property to accept more bytes in request.